# OpenCL: __constant vs. __local?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

Let's say I have a large array of values (still smaller than 64 kB), which is read **very** often in the kernel, but not written to. It can however change from outside. The array has two sets of values, lets call them left and right. 
So the question is, is it faster to get the large array as a __global and write it into __local left and __local right arrays; or get it as a constant __constant large and handle the accesing in the kernel? For example:

```
__kernel void f(__global large, __local left, __local right, __global x, __global y) {
    for(int i; i < size; i++) {
        left[i] = large[i];
        right[i] = large[i + offset];
    }
    ...
    x = foo * left[idx];
    y = bar * right[idx];
}
```

vs:

```
__kernel void f(__constant large, __global x, __global y) {
    ...
    x = foo * large[idx];
    y = bar * large[idx * offset];
}
```

(The indexing is a bit more complicated, but can be made with macros, for instance)
I read that constant memory lives in the global space, so should it be slower?
It will run in a Nvidia card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in the second case you should have someway of making the result available for your CPU. I am assuming you copy back to a `global` `space` after computation.

I think it depends on what you do in the kernel. For example if you kernel computation is heavy (a lot of computations per thread) then the first option might pay of. Why?

- You spend some time copying data from `global large` space to `local` spaces `left` and `right` - *Acceptable*
- You do a lot of computation on the data on local space - *OK*
- You spend some time copying back from `local` `left` and `right` to `global` `large`. - Acceptable.

However if you kernel is relatively light i.e. each thread will do some small computations, then

- You do a few computations with data on `constant` space. Which most probably means you don't need to access it a lot.
- You store intermediate results in local space.
- You spend some time copying back from `local` space to `global` space. - Acceptable.

To sum it up for large kernels the first option is better. For small kernels the second.

P.S. One more thing to note is that if you have multiple kernels that wwork on `large` one after the other, then definitely go with the first option. Because then you can keep the data on global memory space and you don't have to do copy every time you launch a kernel.

EDIT: since you have said it is accessed **very** often then I think you should probably go with the first option.

Comment: Hi thanks, I see your point, but the values of `left` and `right`, or `large`, are not copied back to the CPU. To clarify, picture that the variables `x` and `y` are the things being computed on, and the `large` array is just some weights. The `x` and `y` (not just two, there are many of them) live on the GPU, the kernel is called many times, and in the end only the `x` and `y` are read back to the CPU.

Comment: Oh I see. Then probably option two is better since there is no need for 'large' to be in global memory. Most GPUs have special cache for constant memory space. So It will pay off. Just FYI you don't need the two underscores before the OpenCL keywords anymore, 'constant' is the same as '__constant' now.

Comment: One more thing, from my experience, most of the time for not-so-trival algorithms it is very difficult to estimate performance. Not to mention that optimizations for one architecture might be nightmares for the other. So to answer your question you have to roll up your sleeves, implement both and test it out :).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't know about the '__' being optional, it will surely save some work. 
Yeah, we got the code implemented as the first option, and were discussing maybe reimplementing it using constant, guess we will just have to try it out :P